# Achieve pdfpages's \includepdf with standalone package

Tags: standalone, multiple-files

I would like to have the following dependency:

```
main.tex
|-- part.tex
```

Where each file has its own preamble,
`part.tex` is included as if their pdfs are inserted in `main.pdf`.

I can easily achieve this with [`pdfpages`](https://mirror.lyrahosting.com/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) and `\includepdf`, but I want to compile both files with a single compiling of `main.tex`.

That's why I thought about [`standalone`](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/standalone/standalone.pdf) and `\includestandalone`.
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multi-file_LaTeX_projects#The_standalone_package
but when I include results of `part.tex` in `main.tex` it gets on the same page and with offset.

**How can I include the sub file as a standalone pdf?**

[image]

MWE: main.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[subpreambles=true,mode=buildnew]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}

\title{Main File}
\author{Main author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Front matter}

\section{Importing}
%\includepdf{title.pdf}
\includestandalone{title}

\end{document}
```

title.tex

```
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{showframe}
\title{The title file}
\author{Fibo Kowalsky}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use a tikzpicture with [overlay, remember picture], or simply leave the page blank and use `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0pt,-\paperheight) {\includgraphics ...}}`